# WPF ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBar dont work properly

Tags: wpf, scrollviewer, horizontalscrollview

I have an image inside a ScrollViewer. When I set image width larger, HorizontalScrollBar appeared. Then I set image Width smaller than ScrollViewer With but this ScrollBar still appear, like this:

[image: IMG]
How I can fix this problem? Thank you!

```
<Grid>
    <ScrollViewer
        Name="sv"
        HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
        VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
        PreviewMouseWheel="sv_PreviewMouseWheel">
        <Image Name="img"/>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

Code:

```
    void sv_PreviewMouseWheel(object sender, MouseWheelEventArgs e)
    {
        if ((System.Windows.Forms.Control.ModifierKeys & System.Windows.Forms.Keys.Control) != System.Windows.Forms.Keys.Control) base.OnMouseWheel(e);
        else
        {
            if (e.Delta > 0)
            {
                if (img.ActualHeight < img.Source.Height * 5)
                {
                    double h2 = img.Height = img.ActualHeight * 1.1;
                    double w2 = img.Width = img.Source.Width * h2 / img.Source.Height;
                }
            }

            // PROBLEM HERE:

            else if (img.ActualHeight > 100) img.Height = img.ActualHeight / 1.1;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you're not setting the `Image` control's `Width` property when you're scaling the image down. The image control actually automatically maintains the aspect ratio (the `Stretch` property is set to `Uniform` by default). But while the image resizes, the *control* itself keeps the size you set during scale up. Also note I've corrected your modifier keys check to use WPF instead of Windows Forms:

```
void sv_PreviewMouseWheel(object sender, MouseWheelEventArgs e)
{
    if (Keyboard.Modifiers.HasFlag(ModifierKeys.Control))
    {
        double? h2 = null;
        if (e.Delta > 0)
        {
            if (img.ActualHeight < img.Source.Height * 5)
            {
                h2 = img.Height = img.ActualHeight * 1.1;
            }
        }
        else if (img.ActualHeight > 100)
        {
          h2 = img.Height = img.ActualHeight / 1.1;
        }

        if (h2 != null)
        {
             img.Width = img.Source.Width * h2.Value / img.Source.Height;
        }
    }
}
```

Another solution can be to use a transform to scale the image.

**XAML**

```
<Image Name="img"
       HorizontalAlignment="Center"
       VerticalAlignment="Center">
    <Image.LayoutTransform>
        <ScaleTransform x:Name="imageScale" />
    <Image.LayoutTransform>
</Image>
```

**C#**

```
void sv_PreviewMouseWheel(object sender, MouseWheelEventArgs e)
{
    if (Keyboard.Modifiers.HasFlag(ModifierKeys.Control))
    {
        e.Handled = true; // stops scrolling due to wheel

        if (e.Delta > 0)
        {
            if (imageScale.ScaleX < 5)
            {
                imageScale.ScaleX *= 1.1;
                imageScale.ScaleY *= 1.1;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            imageScale.ScaleX /= 1.1;
            imageScale.ScaleY /= 1.1;
        }
    }
}
```

You can use other transforms as well, such as rotate. Read more about it on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750596.aspx).

Comment: I dont know how to use it, I'm a newbie in WPF, could you send me a sample link that relative to my above task?